# PHP Memory Error error? Installing Flarum

Tags: php, php-5.6, flarum

I am getting the following error when I run setup for Flarum

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes) in **[redacted]/flarum/vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lib/Less/Tree/Ruleset.php** on line 497
```

This is not making any sense to me... its been a long time sense I used php but this makes no sense doesn't that mean that php has 33554432 bytes available and it tried to use 64 bytes and couldn't...

Comment: No, it means that PHP has tried to assign _a further_ 64 bytes _in addition to what it is already using_, and that further 64 bytes has pushed it over the 33554432 byte limit that is set

Comment: Your need to increase memory 33MB is not alot, and if your building assets etc then its going to chew up memory whilst its doing it.

Comment: Increase the memory_limit setting in php.ini

Comment: I think I found the culprit the server has an up time of 600+ days and nscd was using gigs of RAM! So I think it just slowly leaked until it was full I am gona restart it and then I will see if the setup works then and if so I will post that as the solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be the age old give it more ram in the end. Though I did have memory leaks on the server so restarting helped me know it was not the amount of ram actually available to the system that was the issue.

Comment: Nevertheless you should think about rising your memory limit. 32MB seems not that high for current web applications..